# detect mouse state without event handler in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

is there any way I can detect mouse position/button states without working with events in Silverlight (VS2010,C#), I can use left/right mouse button up/down events, but I'm going to detect mouse state outside of these events, what are my options

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you need to use events, but you can make it generic.

You will need to hookup a [MouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousemove%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) handler to your main layout grid (or other container) and check the [MouseButtonEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) argument for the state of the buttons and position (which it inherits from [MouseEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventargs%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)).

You may find this [Mouse Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189029%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) page useful as well.

Comment: thanks HiTech, can I use web services? I've made a webservice for SL-SQL Server connection, does it make sense to use a web service function?

Comment: @Ali_dotNet : You will have to explain what you are trying to do... You could record mouse position etc using a web service if you are trying to log user interaction. Please clarify your intention.

Comment: I'm working on a web-based telemetry system, my users can design an industrial plan, they can drag-drop some images (which are located in a menu) inside canvas, I want my users to be able to perform zoom/pan operation, I've used rendertransform.scale to do so, I scale my whole canvas, in this way when my canvas gets small, I cannot detect mouse state using mouse events, I think these events only work in canvas, this is what I'm going to do, what are my options?

Comment: Mouse events are scaled by rendertransform but only occur within the bounds of the container they are attached too. If you scale your canvas to be very small you may be outside of its bounds. You can transform mouse position from an outer container to relative position within the canvas using MouseEventArgs.GetPosition(*yourcanvas*)